# What is the correct query parameter for "match-all" in a REST filter when there is a default?

Tags: api, rest, url, query-string, url-design

If a REST API endpoint gets all, then filters are easy. Lack of a filter means "get all results".

```
GET /persons - gets all persons
GET /persons?name=john - gets all persons with name of "john"
```

But if there is a default, then I need some way to explicitly *not* set the default filter. Continuing the above example, if each person has a `state`, "approved" or "pending", and if my system is set such that if I do not explicitly specify a state, it will return all "approved":

```
GET /persons - gets all approved persons, because defaults to state=approved
GET /persons?state=approved - same thing, gets all approved persons
GET /persons?state=pending - gets all pending persons
```

**How do I get all persons?** What if there are 10 possible states? Or 100?

I can think of a few ways:

- `GET /persons?state=any` - but then I can never use the actual state `any`
- `GET /persons?state=*` - would work, but feels strange? Or is it?
- `GET /persons?state=` - some URL parsing libraries would complain about a blank query parameter, and does this not imply "state is empty" as opposed to "state is anything"?

How do I say in my GET, "override the default for the state to be anything"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is one answer to this question. As long as you document that the default state is approved well I don't think it matter to the clients if you pass `any`, `*` etc. All of your proposals are fine except the last one. I don't think that is a good one.

If I was designing the API I would use `all` and keep this as a standard. I would also recommend to use paging for all endpoints that returns list of elements. I use `offset` and `limit` as paging query parameters. In my API I return 20 elements as default if the client haven't specified another paging criteria.

Comment: That sounds fair. I am surprised I have not come up against this question yet, but I haven't.

Comment: I did this in the end. Just extended the REST framework http://github.com/deitch/booster to allow the dev to choose what he wants as "any", and it works beautifully. I used '*' for this, but it doesn't matter for the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work for you:

- `GET /persons?state` - gets all persons that have a `state` name, no matter which value
- `GET /persons?state=` - gets all persons that have an empty value for the `state` name

You probably don’t need to differentiate between these two situations, so you could use either one for getting all persons with the `state` name (I just think that the variant without `=` is more beautiful).

FWIW, the [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format](http://www.w3.org/TR/url-1/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded) (i.e., typically used in HTML forms) doesn’t differ between an empty and no value.

As far as the URI standard is concerned, this name-value pair syntax in the query component is [only a convention](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/260205/63183) anyway, so you can use whichever syntax/semantics you wish.

Comment: I agree. I didn't end up going down that route, but used the other answer. The server-side is nodejs, and I have a great REST framework for it http://github.com/deitch/booster so I just extended it to support any form of "clear the filter" the implementor wants.